# ListViewAnimations library android throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-listview, listview-adapter

Im trying to use `ListViewAnimations library` in my test project, therei have  an activity where  i want to implement drug and drop functionality to this list

My **ListViewTest :**

```
public class ListViewTest extends ActionBarActivity {


DynamicListView list;
DataBaseAdapter dataBaseHelper;
private int mNewItemCount;

public List<Cards> list1;
Cards cards;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_test);

    dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseAdapter(this);

    MyAdapter adapter1 = new MyAdapter(this, dataBaseHelper.getData());

    list = (DynamicListView) findViewById(R.id.test_list_view);

    list.enableDragAndDrop();
    list.setDraggableManager(new TouchViewDraggableManager(R.id.linear_layout));
    list.setOnItemMovedListener(new MyOnItemMovedListener(adapter1, list1));
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new MyOnItemLongClickListener(list));

    list.setAdapter(adapter1);

}

private static class MyOnItemLongClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    private final DynamicListView mListView;

    MyOnItemLongClickListener(final DynamicListView listView) {
        mListView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
        return true;
    }
}

private class MyOnDismissCallback implements OnDismissCallback {

    private final MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Nullable
    private Toast mToast;

    MyOnDismissCallback(final MyAdapter adapt) {
        myAdapter = adapt;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(@NonNull final ViewGroup listView, @NonNull final int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
        for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
            myAdapter.remove(position);
        }

        if (mToast != null) {
            mToast.cancel();
        }

    }
}

private class MyOnItemMovedListener implements OnItemMovedListener {

    private final MyAdapter adapter1;
    List<Cards> cardsList;


    private Toast mToast;

    MyOnItemMovedListener(final MyAdapter adapt, List<Cards> list1) {
        adapter1 = adapt;
        cardsList = list1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemMoved(final int originalPosition, final int newPosition) {

    }
}

private class MyOnItemClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private final DynamicListView mListView;

    MyOnItemClickListener(final DynamicListView listView) {
        mListView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
        mListView.insert(position, mNewItemCount);
        mNewItemCount++;
    }
}
}
```

**MyAdapter class :**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cards> {


private Activity mActivity;
private List<Cards> data;
public static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public Resources resources;
Cards cards = null;

int i = 0;


private final Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(final Context context, List d) {

    mContext = context;

    this.data = d;

}
public static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView text;

    public ImageView image;
}


@Override
public View getView(final  int position,final View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){

        vi =(View) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text  = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image_country);

        vi.setTag(holder);

    }else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    if(data.size()<=0){

    }
    else {
        cards = data.get(position);

        holder.text.setText(cards.getName());
    }
    return vi;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public List<Cards> getItems() {
    return super.getItems();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    if (data.size() <= 0)
        return 1;
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
}
```

**Cards** is my getter and setter class, list is populated prom SQlite db  , when my program starts its all ok , but when i try to drug and drop items , i have this: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index (here is current item index), size is 0` . I thiks i didnt announce My List somehere in `OnItemMovedLIstener` but i didnt figure it out how to do it and how rewrite my List

Thanks for answers